# Show $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{(p+k)^2} = -\int_0^1 \frac{x^p \log x}{1-x}\,dx$ holds

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove that
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{(p+k)^2} = -\int_0^1 \frac{x^p \log x}{1-x}\,dx$$
for $p>0$.

I tried to transform LHS as Riemann sum form but failed.

Can anyone give some idea? Many Thanks!

Comment: Please specifiy $p$.

Comment: Complex analysis?

Comment: @TooOldForMath Sorry I forgot this condition, for p>0

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I forgot a condition p>0, so it all number should be real here.

Comment: In the integral, expand $\frac{1}{1-x}$ into a geometric series. Argue that you can interchange summation and integration. Integrate by parts.

Comment: Let $t=1-x$, then expand $\ln(1-x)$ into its well-known Taylor series, and use the fact that $\int\sum=\sum\int$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hurwitz zeta function is defined as

$$\zeta(s,p)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+p)^s}$$

It is absolutely convergent for $p>0$ and $\mathrm{Re} s > 1$. Analogously to the Riemann zeta function it is possible to find an analytic continuation to a meromorphic function on the entire complex plane. Using the Mellin transform one can then obtain the integral representation

$$\zeta(s,p)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{s-1} e^{-pt}}{1-e^{-t}} dt$$

which is valid under the same conditions as above.

Setting $s=2$, we obtain

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+p)^2}=\zeta(2,p)=\int_0^\infty\frac{te^{-pt}}{1-e^{-t}}dt$$

Substituting $x=e^{-t}$, we get

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+p)^2}=-\int_0^1 \frac{x^{p-1}\log(x)}{1-x}dx$$

Now replacing $p-1$ by $p$ we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+p)^2}=-\int_0^1 \frac{x^p\log(x)}{1-x}dx$$